# OpenGL ES 2.0 - Can't find Attribute in Vertex Shader

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, shader, vertex

I've looked for a while for an answer for this - but I'm not having much luck.
All I'm trying to do is pass my normal data into my vertex shader. Positions are passing in correctly, however I'm receiving a "normal attribute not found" error when trying to load my shaders.

My ATTRIB values are enums.

I've created a cube in OpenGL ES 2.0 for Iphone development.

My Shader.vsh looks like this:

```
attribute vec4 normal;
attribute vec4 position;

varying vec4 colorVarying;

uniform mat4 mvp_matrix;

void main()
{
    //Trasform the vertex
    gl_Position = mvp_matrix * position;

    colorVarying = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
}
```

The part where I update attribute values in the drawframe looks like this:

```
// Update attribute values.
glVertexAttribPointer(ATTRIB_VERTEX, 3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, cubeVerticesStrip);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIB_VERTEX);
glVertexAttribPointer(ATTRIB_NORMAL, 3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, cubeNormalsStrip);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIB_NORMAL);
```

And the part where I bind these in my LoadShader function is like this:

```
glBindAttribLocation(program, ATTRIB_VERTEX, "position");
glBindAttribLocation(program, ATTRIB_NORMAL, "normal");
```

Again, the position works. But "normal" cannot be found. Any ideas?

Comment: I hope you make these `glBindAttribLocation` calls before linking, as otherwise they won't have any effect.

Answer (score 13):

`normal` isn't found because your GLSL compiler was smart. It saw that you didn't actually *do* something with `normal`, so it pretends it doesn't exist to save resources.

Also, your normal and position should be `vec3`'s since you're only passing 3 values. This isn't strictly required, but it is better form to make your inputs and attributes match.

Comment: I changed my shader with your suggestion, but I'm still receiving errors. I'm using normal.x as one of my colour variables. The program is failing to link.

Comment: @Ben: You never said that it was a _linker_ error; you just said that "'normal' cannot be found". What exactly is the error?

Comment: @Ben A linker error might be due to mismatching varying names. What does your fragment shader look like?

Comment: Thank you Nicol Bolas! I spent about two hours trying to understand why I can't pass an attribute vertex array. You saved my night sleep ;)